# Win 10 laptop momentarily freezes, fans stop, and then resumes normally

Tags: windows-10, freeze, fan, unresponsive

I have a Dell Alienware 17 Laptop and it operates well, exept I've noticed over the last several days it will momentarily (about for about 1 second) randomly freeze and then resume total normal operation.  Here is how I'd describe the symptoms.  I'll be working on the laptop, usually typing, and then the keyboard will seem unresponsive for a few words, and then I heard all the fans on my laptop stop running -- it goes silent, and then the fans spin back up and all returns to normal.  Everything else seems normal, except this is very annoying.  I ran virus scans, checked that all my drivers are up to date, ruled out most applications that might be running in the background by exiting out of them, but I didn't see anything else that could be causing this issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be causing this momentary pause on my computer before all seems to go back to normal?

Thanks.

Comment: Look in Event Viewer and also in Reliability History for errors that may have caused this.

Comment: I don't see anything close matching the time in Reliability History and queried the last hour in Event View, but nothing really popped out to me except some Windows Security Auditing events that I believe are normal.

Comment: Run a complete set of Hardware tests by the Manufacturer